# Change language of select option with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this form

```
<div class="form-group">
  <select class="form-control" id="dropOficina2" name="dropOficina2"> 
    <option value="">Seleccione el área</option>
    <option  id="Finanzas" name="Finanzas">Finanzas</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

I try these:

```
if ((window.location.href.indexOf("lang=en") > 0)) {
  lang = "English";
  $("#imageOne").attr("src", "/SiteAssets/newimage.png"); //this one works
  $("#Finanzas").val("Finances");
}
```

There are something wrong with `select option` to apply jQuery?

Comment: I'd suggest you use a I18n library for this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -
Change the line

`$("#Finanzas").val("Finances");`

to

`$("#dropOficina2").val("Finances");`

and

`<option id="Finanzas" name="Finanzas">Finanzas</option>`

to

`<option id="Finanzas" value="Finanzas">Finanzas</option>`

```js
 if ((window.location.href.indexOf("lang=en") > 0)) {
   lang = "English";
   $("#imageOne").attr("src", "/SiteAssets/newimage.png"); //this one works
   $("#dropOficina2").val("Finances");
 }
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <select class="form-control" id="dropOficina2" name="dropOficina2">
    <option value="">Seleccione el área</option>
    <option id="Finanzas" value="Finanzas">Finanzas</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: But problem there, if I have another option like <option id="Operacion" value="Operacion">Operacion</option> it doesn´t works right?

Comment: if you want to set `<option id="Operacion" value="Operacion">Operacion</option>` as Selected value then try using `$("#dropOficina2").val("Operacion");`

Comment: But how can I change InnerHtml, my value is changing, but in my page I always get "Finanzas" because thats my inner HTML, there are any way to change this if value change too?

Comment: I´m thinking about    `<option  id="Finanzas" name="Finanzas" label="Finanzas" value="Finanzas"></option>` , but how can I change label value if language is English?

Comment: Can you provide the html code, as you said the value changes? does it change dynamically? what parameters triggers that change? can you post the html code before change and after change?

Comment: I made another question to not confuse with this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39211990/change-label-option-with-jquery

Answer (score 0):

For `val()` to work, you need to have a value attribute in option.

```
<option id="Finanzas" value="Finanzas" name="Finanzas">Finanzas</option>


$("#dropOficina2").val("Finanzas");
```

With no values. Try this:

```
if ((window.location.href.indexOf("lang=en") > 0)) {
   lang = "English";
   $("#imageOne").attr("src", "/SiteAssets/newimage.png"); //this one works
   $('#dropOficina2 option').filter(function() { 
       return ($(this).text() == 'Finanzas'); //filter with text
       //or
       return (this.id == 'Finanzas'); //filter with id
   }).prop('selected', true);
 }
```

Comment: So, if I have another value like `<option id="Operations" id="Operations" name="id="Operations" ">id="Operations"</option>`, I try with value option but it didn´t works

Comment: it should work unless you have multiple selected option.